# pettis integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Maybe this is rather a refernce question on Pettis integrals. Some naive questions arise:

1) Assume that $F$ is Pettis-integrable on $\Omega$ and that $\omega \subset \Omega$ is measurable. Is $f$ then Pettis integrable on $\omega$? It will be Dunford integrable on $\omega$ though, if I understand well.

2) what about "classical results" on (Riemann or Lebesgue) integrals, like the link between integral / differentiation: $F(t) = int_0^t f(s)\,ds$ will be  differentiable with $F'=f$  (in a certain sense and under certain conditions on $f$)

thank you